# Errors with outputting XML values into CSS with XSL

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, xpath

Trying to get all the `<colors>` values from `example.xml` to output them into `example.xsl` but am running into issues when outputting the results onto my website.

Below is an abstraction of the files that I am using...

**example.xml**

```
<plant id="1">
    <colors>
       <green>#00FF00</green>
       <red>#FF0000</red>
       <blue>#0000FF</blue>
    </colors>
</plant>
```

**example.xsl**

```
<xsl:for-each select="colors/*">
    <span class="colors" style="background-color:{colors/*};"></span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am getting an error with `style="background-color:{colors/*};"` between the two { } brackets .

Therefore, what can I do to output the color values of all the elements under `<colors>` into `CSS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already selected the `colors/*` elements in the `for-each` loop, therefore the context element inside the loop is just `.`.

Try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="colors/*">
    <span class="colors" style="background-color:{.};"></span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or to be more precise:

```
<xsl:for-each select="colors/*">
    <span class="colors" style="background-color:{./text()};"></span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should have this:

```
<span class="colors" style="background-color:{.};"></span>
```